# UWP No Speech Option in the Windows.Media.Core.Timed​Metadata​Kind

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, text-to-speech

So the documentation dealing with the Windows.Media.Core.Timed​Metadata​Kind claims there is a 'Speech' Field, Visual Studio 2017 fully updated with UWP and .NET desktop environment, but despite the documentation the enum field does not seem to exist.

Anybody else encountering problems similar to this?

Comment: Then which fields are present?

Comment: Caption 
Chapter 
Custom 
Data 
Description 
Subtitle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what happened. Be wary of this, especially with the upcoming Windows Creator Update.

You have to go into the csproj file and manually change the version of the visual studio tools that you are using.

Edit: As of 30/06/2017, the version of the Visual Studio Tools to use is 15.2, but I suggest looking at the API page of whatever Function or Library you are trying to use, because they will have the details.

Comment: please improve this answer by giving the detailed explanation like which version to choose. And mark it as accepted answer